# How to restream a rtsp from camera using gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, gst-launch

I need to restream a camera's rtsp with a gstreamer. So the clients will connect to the gstreamer server like rtsp://GSTERAMER_IP:PORT/streamname.
Is it passable to take a rtsp url from a camera and just restream is by gstreamer server as it?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use gst-rtsp. There is an example example_launch, it is used like gst-launch but without a sink in the end. You can probably use it like `./example_launch  rtspsrc ... ! [do multiplexing/enccoding]  ! [do something else]`. But I haven't tried it with rtspsrc myself.

Comment: Didn't work. I made it with live555 proxy server.